# SQLite INSERT INTO: no such table

Tags: sqlite

I'm using the DB Browser for SQLite to import some data into a table called 'central':

```
CREATE TABLE "central" (
    `name`  TEXT,
    `summary`   TEXT,
    `nmr`   TEXT UNIQUE,
    `url`   TEXT,
    `type`  TEXT,
    `grid`  TEXT,
    `desc`  TEXT,
    `sources`   TEXT,
    `e` TEXT,
    `n` TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`nmr`)
)
```

I now need to create several tables that contain some of the data from the central table. First, I create an empty table, setting the 'nmr' field from central as the foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE `descs` (
    `nmr`   TEXT,
    `desc`  TEXT,
    `sources`   TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(`nmr`) REFERENCES `nmr`(`central`)
    )
```

I now need to copy all the rows of data from the 'nmr' field in 'central' to the 'nmr' field in 'descs':

```
INSERT INTO descs(nmr)
SELECT nmr
FROM central;
```

But I get the error:

```
no such table: main.nmr: INSERT INTO descs(nmr)
    SELECT nmr
    FROM central;
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOREIGN KEY(`nmr`) REFERENCES `nmr`(`central`)
```

This is a refernce to the column `central` in the table `nmr`.

Comment: Thanks - correct create table statement is:

CREATE TABLE "descs" (
 `nmr` TEXT,
 `desc` TEXT,
 `sources` TEXT,
 FOREIGN KEY(`nmr`) REFERENCES `central`(`nmr`)
 )